# What is the equivalent of 'greater-than-equal-to' or 'less-than-equal-to' WSO2

Tags: xml, database, wso2

I want That the enddate is **less than or equal to** 'request_timestamp'
The enddate here is all the time less than, I tried:

- **&lte;** : isnt accepted while deploying
- **<=** : same behviour as <

The >= is same as > (it's OK because I need >= )

```
<customdblookup>
        <connection>
            <pool>
                <dsName>jdbc/AuditDB</dsName>
            </pool>
        </connection>
        <statement>
            <sql>
              SELECT c.transaction_id, c.application_id, c.institute, c.legal_context, substring(c.endpoint, '[^/]*$') as endpoint, c.action, 
              to_char(c.request_timestamp, 'yyyy-mm-dd') || 'T' || to_char(c.request_timestamp,'hh24:mi:ss.MS') request_timestamp , c.response 
              FROM public.consumer_audit c 
              WHERE c.key_value ~ ? AND c.request_timestamp &gt;= ? AND c.request_timestamp &lt;= ?
            </sql>
            <parameter expression="$ctx:personNumber" type="VARCHAR"/>
            <parameter expression="$ctx:startDate" type="DATE"/>
            <parameter expression="$ctx:endDate" type="DATE"/>
            <result column="transaction_id" name="transaction_id" />
            <result column="application_id" name="application_id" />
            <result column="institute" name="institute" />
            <result column="legal_context" name="legal_context" />
            <result column="endpoint" name="endpoint" />
            <result column="action" name="action" />
            <result column="request_timestamp" name="request_timestamp" />
            <result column="response" name="response" />
        </statement>
    </customdblookup>
```

Thanks for your time;
Regards,

Comment: Hi soukaina, which version are you using? And can you show the specific error in the log during deployment?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can surround the query with `<![CDATA[...]]>` in order to compare by < or > sign

Answer (score 1):

You are using `<customdblookup>` so, it's not standard wso2 mediator?
In WSO2 DB Lookup mediator is example that shows, sql statement surrounded with CDATA:

`<sql><![CDATA[select * from company where name =?]]></sql>`

This is from this documentation: [WSO2 DBLookup Mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.2.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/dBLookup-Mediator/#example).